# SQL statement with several brackets

Tags: sql, brackets

I have a request with several conditions related with OR. In module :

```
$array = array('hostel.postal_code' => $filter_state, 'region.name' => $filter_state, 'hostel.town' => $filter_state, 'state.name' => $filter_state);
$this->db->or_like($array);
```

I see sql:

```
WHERE `bp_hostel`.`status` =  'A'
AND `bp_hostel`.`postal_code`  LIKE '%Vic%'
OR  `bp_region`.`name`  LIKE '%Vic%'
OR  `bp_hostel`.`town`  LIKE '%Vic%'
OR  `bp_state`.`name`  LIKE '%Vic%'
ORDER BY `view_count` desc
```

I have doubts with the request, I would like to set "(...)" to be sure that my sql is correct, like :

```
WHERE `bp_hostel`.`status` =  'A'
AND ( `bp_hostel`.`postal_code`  LIKE '%Vic%'
OR  `bp_region`.`name`  LIKE '%Vic%'
OR  `bp_hostel`.`town`  LIKE '%Vic%'
OR  `bp_state`.`name`  LIKE '%Vic%' )
ORDER BY `view_count` desc
```

I read in doc:

```
You can wrote your requests by hands:
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";
$this->db->where($where);
```

But I found this variant as not convenient, as I do not like to write all conditions as 1 string. In this Methods method there are  some more SQL  conditions...

How to make this?

Comment: this is not about sql, but about your programming language. is it php?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to use the brackets just to be sure the first code of the example is correct? I think the brackets in your example are fundamental because `and` should have priority over `or`, not the other way round. These queries do **not** the same.